# Taking derivative of $L_0$-norm, $L_1$-norm, $L_2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am a little confused about taking derivatives w.r.t. the norms.

**$L_0$-norm**: $L_0$ means number of non-zero elements  in a vector.  Say, I am interested in an $x_i$.

$$\displaystyle\min_{i}(y_i-x_i)^2+c\|x_i \|_{0}$$
The answer depends on $x_i=0$ or not?
My work: take the norm of $x_i$, which is a constant, then, derivative, so it's 0.

**$L_1$-norm**: Manhattan distance.  What should I do?
$$\displaystyle\min_{i}(y_i-x_i)^2+c\|x_i \|_{1}$$

**$L_2$-norm**:Euclidean distance.  What should I do?
$$\displaystyle\min_{i}(y_i-x_i)^2+c\|x_i \|_{2}$$

Answer (score 16):

I'm going to assume that you're talking about partial derivatives and gradients. All of the norm functions that you stated are non-differentiable *somewhere*:

- [$L_0$] This is zero (as you pointed out), but only in places where it isn't interesting. Where it is interesting it's not differentiable (it has jump discontinuities).
- [$L_1$] This norm is not differentiable with respect to a coordinate where that coordinate is zero. Elsewhere, the partial derivatives are just constants, $\pm 1$ depending on the quadrant.
- [$L_2$] Usually people use the 2-norm *squared* so that it's differentiable even at zero. The gradient of $\|x\|_2^2$ is $2x$, but without the square it's $x/\|x\|$ (i.e. it just points away from zero). The problem is that it's not differentiable *at* zero.

If you're trying to do gradient descent with these formulations, the only one that will really work is the squared $L_2$ norm, because that's the only one that's differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I have no background in gradients.  You are correct, the answer for L0-norm is discontinuous.  And what is a coordinate?  Can you point to me a link on all these?

Comment: [Gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient); [Gradient Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

Comment: By coordinate I mean one of the individual $x_i$.

Comment: Got you, but I found a similar L1-norm, they solved it. I hope for a similar answer. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/derivation-of-closed-form-lasso-solution/17786#17786

Comment: At this point, I could care less, could you just solve the discontinuous case?  As a noob, I want to see how it is done, thanks!

Comment: You mean the one for $\|L_0\|$? There isn't a nice closed-form, $L_0$ minimization is NP-Hard.

Comment: well, if x=0, then x=y.  if x≠0, then x=c.  Isn't that the answer?  Yes, for L0-norm.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\|x_i \|_{0}$, if x≠0?

Comment: @Josephine Moeller, thanks for this great answer! Can you expand a bit on the gradient for the L1 norm and how it’s computed? (where it is diffentiable)

Answer (score 1):

For $L_2$ and $L_1$ you can do gradient descent or whatever, the methods are called Ridge Regression and LASSO, respectively.